# How to convert a string to a char?

Tags: java

I'm trying to take a string from a user input using a scanner, and evaluate each character and add 2 to its ASCII value, if I put input of abc, I would like it to output cde. I tried the code below, and got a cannot convert char to int error.

```
String inputString;
System.out.println("Input: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
inputString = sc.nextLine();
sc.close();

int len=inputString.length();
char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{ 
    c[i] +=2;
    c = inputString.toCharArray();
}
System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of code. You can paste the code right into the question! http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Just so you know, `char` doesn't hold an ASCII value; It holds a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. Your algorithm works over the range `a` to 'x'. To make that clear and to prevent erroneous output, do something like `if (c[i] < 'a' or c[i] >'x') throw new Exception("Input characters must be in the range 'a' to 'x'.");`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just write `+= 2` with an array (of any kind) and have Java change the whole array.  You will have to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  name[i] += 2;
}
```

Additionally, you are initializing every character in `name` to the first character of the input string, so it will just be `{'a', 'a', 'a'}`.  You should either change the initialization to be `name[i] = inputString.charAt(i)`, or just make `name = inputString.toCharArray()` to do it all in one go.

Finally, you cannot print arrays in Java like you're trying to do.  You'll need to write something like `System.out.println(String.valueOf(name))`.

Comment: @FredK, yes, and that's even more nonsensical, so I guessed at what the OP was going for in the first place.

Comment: For clarity, you should add `char[] name = inputString.toCharArray()` before the loop, since OP doesn't seem to know of it, and *maybe* `String outputString = new String(name)` after the loop, even though printing the `name` array directly will work too.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I'm new to Java. I edited the code above but when i run the code it just prints my input and doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ZachNaltan Writing `c = inputString.toCharArray();` inside the for loop overwrites your changes and makes `c[i] += 2` do nothing.  Delete that line from inside the for loop.  (And you still haven't fixed `System.out.println(c)`, which will print something nonsensical.  You cannot print arrays like that.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! If i wanted to have it not change special character such as space and punctuation, Could i just write and if else statement?

Comment: Sure, you could do that.